# application/json content type store location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

the result of **content type : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** stored in **Request.Form** in Asp MVC.

but for **"application/json"** i cant find the store location

here is the code that i use:

ajax part

```
    // reading form data
    var form = $("form")[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    var object = {};
    formData.forEach(function(value, key){
      object[key] = value;
    });
    var data = JSON.stringify(object);


    // ajax part
    // POST application/json; charset=utf-8
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("FormSubmit","Home")",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: true,
    success: function(result) { },
    error: function(result) { }
  });
```

Controller Part

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FormSubmit(string input1, string input2)
    {
        var httpContext= HttpContext;
        var response = Response;
        var request = Request;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Just changing the `contentType` isn't enough - you need to actually format `jsonData` correctly for it to be interpreted and deserialised to your action arguments by the MVC ModelBinder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer
i just need to read post Payload

here is the code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FormSubmit()
    {
        Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        var reqMemStream = new MemoryStream(HttpContext.Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Request.ContentLength));
        string reqString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reqMemStream.ToArray());

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string data)
{
    List<YOUR_MODEL_CLASS> payloadObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YOUR_MODEL_CLASS>>(data)(modelData);
    // process your data
}
```

Comment: thanks, i mean access the raw data not from (string data), for example from "request.form" part